# Highlighting a phone number on a web page for firefox add-on

Tags: jquery, regex, firefox-addon-sdk, highlighting, phone-number

I am trying to develop a Firefox add-on using the documentation provided by the MDN. My regex works well when tested on a sample HTML page. But, the problem occurs when developing an add-on. Following is my code which is saved by the name my-scripts.js.

```
$("body:first").each(function(){
// Create a REGEX Expression to detetc a phone number
var regex =/\+\d{0,3}[-.\s]?\(?\d?\)?[-.\s]?\s?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}[-.\s]?\d{5}/g;
var text = $(this).html();
text = text.replace(regex, "<a href=\"javascript:;\">$&</a>");
$("body:first").html(text);
});
```

Following is the main Javascript file called main.js.

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var { MatchPattern } = require("sdk/util/match-pattern");
var pattern = new MatchPattern("http://example.com/*");
var self = require("sdk/self");
pageMod.PageMod({
contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.11.0.js"), self.data.url("my-script.js")]
});
```

My regex is perfect, but doesn't detect numbers on a given web page

Examples

```
+111111111111
+11 (1) 111 11 11111
+11 (1) 111 11-11111
+11 111 11 11111
+11 (1) 1111 111111111
+11111111111111
+11 1111 111111111
```

Comment: Please give examples of phone numbers that this should match.

Comment: @MElliott: these numbers should get detected if present on a web page.

Comment: Yes, must be something in your main.js file..  It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/PtLc5/ and here: http://regex101.com/r/jJ6cO7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (lower level) match pattern API is built into the (higher level) PageMod API in the form of the [`include` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) in the constructor. The only reason the match-pattern module is linked to in the PageMod docs is so that you have an idea of how the matching strings work.

So if want your add-on to be applied to `"http://example.com/*"`, main.js should look like:

```
var {data} = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://example.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.11.0.js"), data.url("my-script.js")]
});
```

If I misinterpreted that (the match-pattern lines were in there for another reason), and you want your regex to be applied to every page, use `include: '*'`.

Comment: Thanks...It worked well..But on some pages the add-on slows down the entire web-page and the numbers don't get detected but after refreshing the page the number gets highlighted..Is there problem with the add-on or any changes to be done in order to fasten up....

Comment: What match pattern are you using? Things you might try: set the [`contentScriptWhen` constructor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod(options)), set the `attachTo` constructor property to `['top', 'existing']`, use Jquery 2.x, remove the for-each loop.

Comment: @willma: I am using Regex to detect phone numbers. My regex works perfect,but it detects some other numbers present under id tags apart from detecting the actual phone numbers. I have tried the constructor properties, but it doesn't affect the plug-in,but the delay in loading the page is decreased.

Comment: @Adi What I meant was what is the value of your `include` parameter on the constructor? Page-mods attach to the main document and every iframe, so using `attachTo: 'top'` should improve performance, as only the main document will be searched. I'm not sure how to improve performance beyond that. Might be a good topic for another question.